# Scalaz validation NEL mkString

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz

i'm trying to learn scalaz validation, and given this piece of code:

```
          AuthorValidator.validate(author) match {
            case scalaz.Success(authorValidated) => onSuccess(authorService.addAuthor(authorValidated)) { extract: Int =>
                complete(StatusCodes.OK -> extract+"")
              }
            case scalaz.Failure(failure) => complete(StatusCodes.Accepted, failure mkString "/") // this piece won't work
          }
        }
```

I want to obtain formatted string from `failure : NonEmptyList[String]`. Basically, i can't use mkString. Do you know if scalaz provide some way to format NEL ?

Comment: You may want to look at the `Show` typeclass http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Show.html

Comment: OK Thank you, i was going through scalaz for the past few days and I just can't remember everything :)

Comment: I'd recommend not using the `Show` type class for this kind of thing, since `NonEmptyList[String]` already has an instance, and it doesn't do what you want. In general I'd only use `Show` for debugging purposes, not for presenting data to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NonEmptyList` is just a list with one extra guarantee (non-emptiness), so you can always safely convert one to an ordinary Scala `List` in order to use methods like `mkString`:

```
import scalaz.NonEmptyList, scalaz.syntax.foldable._

def formatNel(nel: NonEmptyList[String]): String = nel.toList.mkString("/")
```

The `foldable` syntax import provides the `toList` method via the `Foldable` instance for `NonEmptyList`. You could also use `nel.list.toList` to convert first to a `scalaz.IList`, but that's a little more verbose and may be less efficient for large lists (off the top of my head I'm not sure).

There are also lots of other ways you could write this directly, without converting to a Scala list. One would be to convert to an `IList` and then use `intersperse` and `suml`:

```
import scalaz.NonEmptyList, scalaz.std.string._, scalaz.syntax.foldable._

def formatNel(nel: NonEmptyList[String]): String = nel.list.intersperse("/").suml
```

For something like formatting as a string, though, I'd probably stick to `toList.mkString`, since it's clear, familiar, and may be more efficient since it's less generic than `suml` (although that's unlikely to matter much in most cases).

Comment: Thank you, basically i implemented it in my code, after noticing that Show is deprecated, after that i imported foldable, and saw that implicitly i had power (yeah !) to convert it to list (if you don't know scala like your native language it sometimes is a pain in the ass with all implicits :) ), so i did this ! I wanted to answer to my question but i didn't want to seem like arogant, so i waited, thanks to you now i know that my last solution was good :)